# JS - Submit parameter's value with "&"

Tags: javascript, parameters, form-submit

I´m working with a **.js** referring to a form.

In a function it sets the form's action and then submit it.

```
document.forms[0].action = "FileController.do?action=genFile&fileType="+ft+"&answType="+at;
document.forms[0].submit();
```

The problem is that **answType**'s value sometimes has an "**&**" on it, like "**M&M**", so when I try to get that value like this:

```
String answer = request.getParameter("answType");
```

I only get the first "**M**" and lost the rest of the value.

I know that's because parameters are separated by "**&**".

But is there a workaround for this?

I can't change the original data.

Thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encodeURIComponent(string)` will convert characters with special meaning in URLs (such as `&`) to their escape sequences.